# How exactly spring.http.multipart.enabled is different from spring.servlet.multipart.enabled?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In Spring Boot, for multipart uploads, I see many of the tutorial sites suggests to have one of the below properties:

`spring.http.multipart.enabled=false`

or

`spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true`

Can someone explain why these settings and their use cases? Especially if I set the property `spring.http.multipart.enabled=false` , then why `spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true`

I tried searching through Stack Overflow, but did not find any relevant posts for this one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`spring.http.multipart.enabled` has been **replaced** with `spring.servlet.multipart.enabled`

If you're using **Spring Boot 2.0.0** or later you should use `spring.servlet.multipart.enabled`

**See also:**

- [`additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/ce9626d00fcaf12621278ac0a008813f61cbbff3/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json#L1548)
- [Spring Boot Reference of **1.5.19.RELEASE** version](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.19.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix) (the **Common application properties** section lists `spring.http.multipart.enabled`).
- [Spring Boot reference of **2.0.0.RELEASE** version](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) (replaced with `spring.servlet.multipart.enabled`)
- [Upgrading from an Earlier Version of Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-upgrading-from-an-earlier-version)
- [`MultipartProperties` (1.5.19.RELEASE)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.19.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/MultipartProperties.java#L46)
- [`MultipartProperties` (2.0.0.RELEASE)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/MultipartProperties.java#L46)