# Why Spring App is saving the file when MultipartFile Post Method is called?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, jar

Probably it is a ridiculous question but I wonder the answer. I wrote an endpoint to get a file to save it to aws s3 as:

```
@PostMapping("/media")
    @Operation(summary = "Save Media", security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "BearerJWT"))
    public ResponseEntity<MediaDto> saveMedia(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("MediaDto") MediaDto MediaDto) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(mediaService.saveMedia(MediaDto, file));
    }
```

The code is working good. I just want to add this file to s3 in my service class and it is ok too but whenever I send a file to this endpoint than the project is saving the file into the project folders.

1-On my local, is it something normal or can I stop this saving and just use it in service method and skip it ? Should I delete the file manually or delete it via code ?

2-More serious question mark in my mind is that I get build jar file from the project and deploying it to the server and it is running on server from a jar file. What is happening when I send file to this endpoint on server ? Is the server is still saving the file in somewhere on server or just process it and skip it ?

Answer (score 0):

This question seems a temp file question , Uploading a file will generator a temp file.

I've found a issue on Github [How does one specify a temp directory for file uploads in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923682/how-does-one-specify-a-temp-directory-for-file-uploads-in-spring-boot) , Maybe help you.