# Spring boot multi part files upload storing data wondering

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this service in spring boot app:

```
@Service
public class FileStorageService {
    private final Path root = Paths.get("uploads");

    public void init() {
        try {
          Files.createDirectories(root);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize folder for upload!");
        }
      }
    
      public ResponseEntity<?> save(MultipartFile[] files) {
        if (files.length == 0) {
            //return ResponseEntity.badRequest();
        }

       
    
        Arrays.asList(files).stream().forEach(file -> {
            try {
                // Get the file and save it somewhere
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                Path path = Paths.get(root + File.separator + file.getOriginalFilename());
                Files.write(path, bytes);
    
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
        
    }
    
}
```

There is some folder for saving files "uploads". And i am now wondering what is

```
spring.servlet.multipart.location=
```

setting used for. Is this just folder where raw data from request are stored before they are saved in "uploads" folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one specify a temp directory for file uploads in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923682/how-does-one-specify-a-temp-directory-for-file-uploads-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/MultipartProperties.html) document for `spring.servlet.multipart.location`,

> location specifies the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
> When not specified, a temporary directory will be used.

I dig around some internal code and found out that, it depends on the `spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold` configuration. As mentioned in the doc

> specifies the size threshold after which files will be written to disk. The default is 0.

If you mention any non-zero value then it will attempt to store that much in memory first before, writing to disk.
For your case, if you mention any location in `spring.servlet.multipart.location` the file will directly stored over that location only.
You may also want to check  `spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size` and `spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size` property.

Comment: ok, thanks, still wondering how to do it in my case, cause i have system on pretty small disk and there will app running and then i have connect large disk and i want all files go straight to that external connected disk, to avoid the situation that the file is too large. I will be uploading files about 2GB. Can you just hint me some solution exactly for my case?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I miss understood the internal code. For you just configured the `spring.servlet.multipart.location` keeping  `spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold` to default value to zero. It will store all files directly that place only. But as you mention you want to upload file about 2GB you have to change `max-file-size` and `max-request-size` as well accordingly.