# Spring Multipart upload with docker --read-only

Tags: docker, spring-boot, undertow

Hello I am trying to run my container with --read-only, but when I receive a request for multipart upload i tries to create a temporary file:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /tmp/undertow3773194840223053389upload: Read-only file system.
```

Is it possible to make it only in memory?

thanks =)

Comment: Could you edit your post to show how do you start your container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like below

```
docker run -it --read-only --tmpfs /tmp alpine sh
```

This will allow you to write files in `/tmp`. So what you need is a additional `--tmpfs /tmp` in your `docker run` command

Comment: I was trying to avoid write even in the temporary file system. but I don't think there is a way to do it.

Tried to increase the spring threshold, I thought it would make the file stay in memory: 
spring.http.multipart.file-size-threshold=100MB //example

Comment: The error does not happen when I start the application, it is when I post the files.

Comment: That is because the post file needs to be written to some place before it is handed over to spring boot. See if you can use/configure `maxInMemorySize`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952633/will-spring-hold-contents-in-memory-or-stores-in-the-disk